# Slack connection error. Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, python-requests, slack-api, urllib3

I have facing connection issue in slack api. I ran this code inside the vagrant Ubuntu 14.04.4 virtual machine.

```
sc = SlackClient(token)
print sc.api_call("api.test")
```

I tried above example code from [slackclient](http://python-slackclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?badge=latest) library and getting following error.

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='slack.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded
>   with url: /api/api.test (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: No. I have installed vagrant machine(virtual ubuntu machine) in my windows.

Comment: From your vagrant box, can you do `dig +short slack.com`?